# Por qué devuelve el error cannot access 'variable' before initialization?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Buen día a todos!

Tengo un javascript que básicamente me funciona para un carrito de compras. Actualmente ya lo tengo funcionando en una parte de mi proyecto, pero, estoy queriendo hacerlo funcionar en otra parte y me devuelve el error de la pregunta.

```
const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach(addToCartButton => {
    addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
});

const vaciarButton1 = document.querySelector('.vaciarButton1');
vaciarButton1.addEventListener('click', vaciarButtonClicked);


const shoppingCartItemContainer = document.querySelector('.shoppingCartItemContainer');

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    const button = event.target;
    const item = button.closest('.cardsita')
    const itemTitle = item.querySelector('.for-checkbox-tools').textContent;
    const itemPrice = item.querySelector('.checkbox-tools').value;
    const titulo_plan = item.querySelector('.titulo_plan').value;
    const prima = item.querySelector('.prima').value;
    const modal_id = item.querySelector('.modal_id').value;
    addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach(btn => btn.disabled = true);

    addItemToShoppingCart(itemTitle, itemPrice, titulo_plan, prima, modal_id);
}

function addItemToShoppingCart(itemTitle, itemPrice, titulo_plan, prima, modal_id) {
    const shoppingCartRow = document.createElement('div');
    const shoppingCartContent = `
        <div class="row shoppingCartItem">
            <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="${titulo_plan}">
            <input type="hidden" name="equipo" value="${itemTitle}">
            <input type="hidden" name="seguro" value="Plan de protección celular">
            <input type="hidden" name="precio" value="${itemPrice}">
            <input type="hidden" name="prima" value="${prima}">
            <input type="hidden" name="modal_id" value="${modal_id}">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="center">Producto</th>
                        <th class="center">Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center shoppingCartItemTitle"${titulo_plan}">${titulo_plan}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center shoppingCartItemTitle">Plan de protección celular</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center shoppingCartItemTitle">${itemTitle}</td>
                        <td class="center shoppingCartItemPrice" style="display: none">${itemPrice}</td>
                        <td class="center"><i class="material-icons red-text buttonDelete" style="cursor: pointer;">close</i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center shoppingCartItemTitle">Prima: $ ${prima}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="divider"></div>
        </div>
    `;
    
    shoppingCartRow.innerHTML = shoppingCartContent;
    console.log(shoppingCartRow);
    shoppingCartItemContainer.append(shoppingCartRow);

    shoppingCartRow.querySelector('.buttonDelete').addEventListener('click', removeShoppingCartItem);
    updateShoppingCartTotal()
}

function updateShoppingCartTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    const shoppingCartTotal = document.querySelector('.shoppingCartTotal');
    const shoppingCartItems = document.querySelectorAll('.shoppingCartItem');

    shoppingCartItems.forEach((shoppingCartItem) => {
        const shoppingCartItemPriceElement = shoppingCartItem.querySelector('.shoppingCartItemPrice');
        const shoppingCartItemPrice = Number(shoppingCartItemPriceElement.textContent.replace('$', ''));
        total = total + shoppingCartItemPrice;
    });
    shoppingCartTotal.innerHTML = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
}

function removeShoppingCartItem(event) {
    const buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.closest('.shoppingCartItem').remove();
    updateShoppingCartTotal();
    addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach(btn => btn.disabled = false);
}

function vaciarButtonClicked() {
    shoppingCartItemContainer.innerHTML = '';
    updateShoppingCartTotal();
    addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach(btn => btn.disabled = false);
```

Ese JS lo mando a traer en la consulta que hago de ajax, ya que los items que quiero agregar al carrito los obtengo con una consulta de PHP:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#price_range").slider();
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){

            filter_data();

            function filter_data()
            {
                $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
                var action = 'fetch_data';
                var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
                var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
                var marca = get_filter('marca');
                var ram = get_filter('ram');
                //filtro de búsqueda (input)
                var busqueda = $('#busqueda').val();
                console.log(busqueda);
                $.ajax({
                    url:"fetch_data.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, marca:marca, ram:ram, busqueda:busqueda},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('.filter_data').html(data);
                        $.getScript("../../js/carrito_catalogo.js");
                        /* Paginación */
                            function getPageList(totalPages, page, maxLength){
                                function range(start, end){
                                    return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_,i) => i + start);
                                }

                                var sideWidth = maxLength < 9 ? 1 : 2;
                                var leftWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 3) >> 1;
                                var rightWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 3) >> 1;

                                if(totalPages <= maxLength){
                                    return range(1, totalPages);
                                }

                                if(page <= maxLength - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth){
                                    return range(1, maxLength - sideWidth - 1).concat(0, range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
                                }

                                if(page >= totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth){
                                    return range(1, sideWidth).concat(0, range(totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth - leftWidth, totalPages));
                                }

                                return range(1, sideWidth).concat(0, range(page - leftWidth, page + rightWidth), 0, range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
                            }

                            $(function(){
                                var numberOfItems = $(".poderosa_paginacion .card").length;
                                if (screen.width < 1024) {
                                    var limitPerPage = 4; //cantidad de cards visibles
                                }else{
                                    var limitPerPage = 6; //cantidad de cards visibles
                                }
                                
                                var totalPages = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / limitPerPage);
                                var paginationSize = 7;
                                var currentPage;

                                function showPage(whichPage){
                                    if(whichPage < 1 || whichPage > totalPages) return false;

                                    currentPage = whichPage;

                                    $(".poderosa_paginacion").hide().slice((currentPage - 1) * limitPerPage, currentPage * limitPerPage).show();

                                    $(".pagination li").slice(1, -1).remove();

                                    getPageList (totalPages, currentPage, paginationSize).forEach(item => {
                                        $("<li>").addClass("page-item").addClass(item ? "current-page": "dots")
                                        .toggleClass("active", item === currentPage).append($("<a>").addClass("page-link")
                                        .attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text(item || "...")).insertBefore(".next-page");
                                    });
                                    $(".previous-page").toggleClass("disable", currentPage === 1);
                                    $(".next-page").toggleClass("disable", currentPage === totalPages);
                                    return true;
                                }
                                $(".pagination").append(
                                    $("<li>").addClass("page-item").addClass("previous-page").append($("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text("Anterior")),
                                    $("<li>").addClass("page-item").addClass("next-page").append($("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text("Siguiente"))
                                );
                                $(".poderosa_paginacion").show();
                                showPage(1);

                                $(document).on("click", ".pagination li.current-page:not(.active)", function(){
                                    return showPage(+$(this).text());
                                });
                                $(".next-page").on("click", function(){
                                    return showPage (currentPage + 1);
                                });
                                $(".previous-page").on("click", function(){
                                    return showPage (currentPage - 1);
                                });
                            });
                        /* Fin paginacion*/
                    }
                });
            }

            function get_filter(class_name)
            {
                var filter = [];
                $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
                    filter.push($(this).val());
                });
                return filter;
            }

            $('.common_selector').click(function(){
                filter_data();
            });

            $('.busqueda').on('change',function(){
                filter_data();
            });

            $('#price_range').slider({
                range:true,
                min:5,
                max:100,
                values:[5, 100],
                step:5,
                stop:function(event, ui)
                {
                    $('#price_show').html('$' + ui.values[0] + '.00 - $' + ui.values[1] + '.00');
                    $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
                    $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
                    filter_data();
                }
            });
        });   
    </script>
```

Lo que me parece raro es que lo tengo funcionando en otro lado con el mismo código y sin problemas, y el error me lo devuelve como si lo tuviera en el jquery.min.js pero ahí no tengo nada referente a ese código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no puedes iniciar `filter_data();` y después poner su función debe ser al revés primero la función y después invocarla

Comment: Hola @Artes! Gracias por la corrección, ya hice el cambio. Aún así el error sigue pasando e igual, todo lo demás que tengo lo hace bien.

Comment: no veo tu `.shoppingCartItemContainer` declarado como etiqueta html, y tampoco veo una creación con `createElement`, por lo que supongo que esta en otro lado del html, es correcto?; y como lo estas capturando con `const shoppingCartItemContainer = document.querySelector('.shoppingCartItemContainer');` al momento de hacer el append que tienes no encuentra una referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Eso ocurre debido al [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) de Javascript, que lo que hace es mover las definiciones de ciertas variables/funciones al inicio del scope (no sus valores de inicializacion).

Las declaraciones con `var` y `function` son "hoisteadas" (no se como sea su traducción al español), las declaraciones con `let` o `const` no.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente fragmento:

```js
console.log(a);
const a = "hola";
```

lanza:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization`

Pero el siguiente fragmento no saca error, solo dice que la variable tiene el valor undefined:

```js
console.log(a);
var a = "hola";
```

Porque basicamente lo que el hoisting hace es declarar las funciones al inicio del scope, en este caso siendo similar a:

```js
var a;
console.log(a);
a = "hola";
```

Eso mismo sucede en tu código.

Tienes la declaración `const shoppingCartItemContainer`  y luego la declaración `function addItemToShoppingCart(...)` que usa esa variable, por lo tanto, debido al "Hoisting" la declaración de la funcion pasa a estar antes del const, y por eso la funcion dice que `shoppingCartItemContainer` no está definida.

***SOLUCIÓN***

Podrías

1. Declarar `shoppingCartItemContainer` con `var` en vez de `const` para que también quede afectado por el "Hoisting".
2. Declarar la funcion como `const` también así: `const addItemToShoppingCart = (itemTitle, itemPrice, titulo_plan, prima, modal_id) => { .... }`

Comment: Hola! Probé declararla como `var` en lugar de `const` pero sigue devolviendo exactamente el mismo error.
También probé declarar como `const` la función de "addItemToShoppingCart..." pero al hacer eso aparte de que me devuelve el error, tampoco me trae las variables en la consola

Comment: Seguro que con `var` te sale exactamente el mismo error? con la misma variable? No será el mismo error pero con la variable `addToShoppingCartButtons` que por lo que veo en tu código tiene exactamente el mismo problema. La declaras con const y la usas dentro de funciones que declaras mas abajo.